# adapter addAll replaces the items of previous page, android

Tags: android, android-adapter

When the user hit the bottom of my listview, the second page is loaded and displayed. The problem is that, when it happens, the items of the first page are replaced with the ones of the second page. This video show the behaviour: https://www.ubris.design/video.mp4
and this is my code, inside the respomnse callback of my webservice:

```
try {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);

        JSONObject response = obj.getJSONObject("response");
        Integer count = Integer.parseInt(response.getString("count"));

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),count+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        inputItems.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            JSONObject tmp = response.getJSONObject(i+"");

            id = tmp.getString("id");
            materia = tmp.getString("materia");
            adsce = tmp.getString("adsce");
            nomeCompleto = tmp.getString("nomeCompleto");
            matricola = tmp.getString("matricola");

            username = tmp.getString("username");
            password = tmp.getString("password");
            uni = tmp.getString("uni");
            descrizione = tmp.getString("descrizione");

            type = tmp.getString("type");
            voto = tmp.getString("voto");
            votanti = tmp.getString("votanti");
            ts = tmp.getString("ts");

            //url
            siteTitle = tmp.getString("siteTitle");
            siteDescription = tmp.getString("siteDescription");
            siteImage = tmp.getString("siteImage");
            address = tmp.getString("address");

            //file
            filename = tmp.getString("filename");
            filesize = tmp.getString("filesize");

            combinedSize = tmp.getString("combinedSize");

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filename+address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            inputItems.add(new DTODocSelected(id, materia, adsce, nomeCompleto, matricola, null, null, uni, descrizione,type, voto, votanti, ts,
                    siteTitle, siteDescription, siteImage, address,
                    filename, filesize, combinedSize
                    ));
        }





    } catch (Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }



    if(inputItems.size() > 0){


        if(page == 0){

            adapter = new AdapterDocMateriaDocsSelect(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.id.activity_docs_doc_selected, inputItems);


            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);

            listView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
            listView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            listView.destroyDrawingCache();
            listView.buildDrawingCache(false);
            listView.getDrawingCache(false);


            double vv = Integer.valueOf(counterCC);
            double pagineMax = Math.ceil( vv / 5);
            int pagineMaxInt = (int) pagineMax;
            if(page == (pagineMaxInt - 1)){
                pagination = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pagination false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        } else {

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+inputItems.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            double vv = Integer.valueOf(counterCC);
            double pagineMax = Math.ceil( vv / 5);
            int pagineMaxInt = (int) pagineMax;
            if(page == (pagineMaxInt - 1)){
                pagination = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pagination false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }





            adapter.addAll(inputItems);

            //inputItems.clear();
            //listView.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
            //listView.smoothScrollToPosition(page * 5);


        }



    } else {

        pagination = false;
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "zero", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Post details of you `adapter.addAll` method

Comment: Why you are clearing inputitems list ? May be it is the reason ! Create a temporary local list and add that list to inputems list. 
@Edit:  Before the for loop.

Comment: I clean input items because when it load the second page it will add again the first page items and this cause a indexoutofbound exception.

Answer (score 0):

to solve I just replaced adapter.addAll(inputItems); with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and removed inputItems.clear();